# Watson dialog node doesn't make a call for the action when I am sending a text message to the api of watson

Tags: python, api, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I am calling an action from a certain dialog node in Watson assistant and the try it out panel it works perfectly without problems but when I am using my code and calling the Watson API the response is correct but it doesn't have the information from the action. It's like it doesn't make the call for the action.
I used the code from the documentation and it works but it doesn't give the results from the action.

```
import JSON
import ibm_watson

service = ibm_watson.AssistantV2(
    iam_apikey='{apikey}',
    version='2019-02-28',
    url='{url}'
)

response = service.message(
    assistant_id='{assistant_id}',
    session_id='{session_id}',
    input={
        'message_type': 'text',
        'text': '< The input that I enter to get the wanted results >'
    }
).get_result()

print(json.dumps(response, indent=2))
```

I am expecting this: 
Product < example > description is: "< example description >"

But instead I get this:
Product $result.product is: "$result.description"

Can someone please help me with this? Do I need to change something

Answer (score 0):

If everything is set up similarly, there are chances that the difference stems from different API versions. See the [Watson Assistant release notes](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/assistant?topic=assistant-release-notes#release-notes) for the current API versions for the V1 and V2 APIs as well as the "Try it out".

Right now the "Try it out" is at `2018-07-10` and the V1 and V2 APIs are at `2019-02-28`. You could try to set the version in your code to `2018-07-10`, too.

Comment: I changed the version to 2018-07-10 but it still has the same problem. I also tried the version 2018-12-03 for search skill but nothing changed.